# hidden value not submit in form

Tags: php, html

my php code is like this i am not get "nextProcessId" on form submit. in hidden variable i get value but when i am submit this form i can not submit "nextProcessId"

```
 $processId = isset($_REQUEST['processId']) ? $_REQUEST['processId'] : 0;
     $nextProcessId  = isset($_REQUEST['nextProcessId']) ? $_REQUEST['nextProcessId'] : 0;

      if($processId > 0)
      {
       echo"<br>m". $updateStatus = "UPDATE process 
                          SET 
                          status = 'I',
                          nextProcessId = ".$nextProcessId."
                        WHERE processId = ".$processId;
        $updateStatusRes = mysql_query($updateStatus);
        if(!$updateStatusRes)
        {
          echo "Process Reverse Fail";
        }
    }
```

here is my from code here i am submit hidden value "nextprocessid" hidden is like that right in text box i am getting value but if me pass in hidden i can not submit this value

```
<form action="reciveEntry.php" method="POST" id="formId">
<table align="center" border="1"> 
    <h2 align="center">Process Recive List</h2>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="table1">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="table1">Process Date</th>
        <th class="table1">Item Name</th>
        <th class="table1">Worker Name</th>
        <th class="table1">Recive Process Name</th>
        <th class="table1">Design No</th>
        <th class="table1">Design Weight</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</tbody>
  {section name="sec" loop=$designArray}
  <tr>
    <input type="" value="{$designArray[sec].nextProcessId}" name="nextProcessId">
    <td class="table1" align="center"><a onclick="return confirm('Do You Want To Delete??');" href="reciveEntry.php?processId={$designArray[sec].processId}">Delete</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="desWet[]" value="{$designArray[sec].desWet}">
    <td class="table1" align="center">{$designArray[sec].processDate}</td>
    <td class="table1" align="center">{$designArray[sec].itemNm}</td>
    <td class="table1" align="center">{$designArray[sec].workerName}</td>
    <td class="table1" align="center">{$designArray[sec].processNm}</td>
    <td class="table1" align="center">{$designArray[sec].dNo}</td>
    <td class="table1" align="center">{$designArray[sec].desWet}</td>
  </tr>
  {/section}
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: yes i show my console code there is no error.. and my form is post as u insist i am using get method but there is no difference in output..

Comment: @anantkumarsingh `$_REQUEST` contains both `POST` and `GET` parameters.

Comment: with post method same result @anantkumarsingh

Comment: here i am updating my from code @anantkumarsingh

Comment: yes on click on delete i want execute update query

Comment: @PrashantBhatt PLEASE UP-VOTE THE ANSWER ALSO.THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in chat you need to do this:

Just write your link in this manner:

```
<td class="table1" align="center"><a onclick="return confirm('Do You Want To Delete??');" href="reciveEntry.php?processId={$designArray[sec].processId}&nextProcessId={$de‌​signArray[sec].nextProcessId}">Delete</td>
```

And PHP just do these changes:

```
$processId = isset($_REQUEST['processId(copy form your link and past)']) ? $_REQUEST['processId'] : 0;
$nextProcessId = isset($_REQUEST['nextProcessId(copy from your link and past']) ? $_REQUEST['nextProcessId'] : 0;
echo $processId ;
echo $nextProcessId ;
```

Note:- I am not writing full code. You already understand it. Strang but this only works, as we come to end of conclusion in the chat.